# Convert this LINQ to dynamic Expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have an extension in my project that let's me sort an `IEnumerable` with a string, so that sorting can be done more dynamically.

So, if I have these models:

```
public MyModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string RecordName {get; set;}
    public ChildModel MyChildren {get; set;}
}

public ChildModel 
{
    public int ChildModelId {get; set;}
    public string ChildName {get; set;}
    public DateTime SavedDate {get; set;}
}
```

I could sort my list like this:

```
var myList = db.MyModel.Where(m => m.IsActive);
myList
    .OrderBy(m => m.MyChildren
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.SavedDate).FirstOrDefault().SavedDate);
```

or:

```
var myList = db.MyModel.Where(m => m.IsActive);
myList.OrderBy(m => m.MyChildren.Max(c => c.SavedDate);
```

But I want to be able to dynamically sort, based on user options. So I would like this:

```
var myList = db.MyModel.Where(m => m.IsActive);
myList.OrderByField("MyChildren.SavedDate");
```

The extension method I have so far looks like this:

```
public static class MkpExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, string sortExpression)
    {
        sortExpression += "";
        string[] parts = sortExpression.Split(' ');
        bool descending = false;
        string fullProperty = "";

        if (parts.Length > 0 && parts[0] != "")
        {
            fullProperty = parts[0];

            if (parts.Length > 1)
            {
                descending = parts[1].ToLower().Contains("esc");
            }

            ParameterExpression inputParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
            Expression propertyGetter = inputParameter;

            foreach (string propertyPart in fullProperty.Split('.'))
            {
                var checkIfCollection = propertyGetter.Type.GetInterfaces()//(typeof (ICollection<>).FullName);
                    .Any(x => x.IsGenericType &&
                        (x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>) || x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)));

                if (checkIfCollection)
                {
                    var pgType = propertyGetter.Type;
                    var childType = pgType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                    var childProp = childType.GetProperty(propertyPart);

                    ParameterExpression childInParam = Expression.Parameter(childType, "c");
                    var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(childInParam, childProp);                      
                    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, childInParam);
                    // At this point, orderByExp is c => c.ActionDate

                    // Now I want to build the expression tree to handle the order by
                    XXXXX This is where I need help.
                }
                else
                {
                    // This handles a singular property. Like "MyChildren.ChildName"
                    // and this part does work
                    PropertyInfo prop = propertyGetter.Type.GetProperty(propertyPart);
                    if (prop == null)
                        throw new Exception("No property '" + fullProperty + "' in + " + propertyGetter.Type.Name + "'");
                    propertyGetter = Expression.Property(propertyGetter, prop);
                }
            }

            Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(propertyGetter, typeof(object));
            var getter = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, inputParameter).Compile();

            if (descending)
            {
                // This would be like 
                //  list.OrderByDescending(m => m.MyChildren
                //      .OrderByDescending(c => c.SavedDate).FirstOrDefault().SavedDate);
                return list.OrderByDescending(getter);
            }
            else
            {
                // This would be like 
                //  list.OrderBy(m => m.MyChildren
                //      .OrderByDescending(c => c.SavedDate).FirstOrDefault().SavedDate);
                return list.OrderBy(getter);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)

Comment: @Ash I don't see how that handles sorting on a property of a collection property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should use the following [`Expression.Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which allows you to build an expression for calling static generic methods (what are all the LINQ extension methods).

To build the equivalent of expression like this

```
m => m.MyChildren.OrderByDescending(c => c.SavedDate).FirstOrDefault().SavedDate
```

you can use the following snippet:

```
// At this point, orderByExp is c => c.ActionDate
var orderByDescendingCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { childType, orderByExp.Body.Type },
    propertyGetter, orderByExp
);
var firstOrDefaultCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", new Type[] { childType },
    orderByDescendingCall
);
propertyGetter = Expression.Property(firstOrDefaultCall, childProp);
```

But note that you'll get NRE if the collection is empty.

So you'd better build an expression like this:

```
m => m.MyChildren.OrderByDescending(c => c.SavedDate)
   .Select(c => (DateTime?)c.SavedDate).FirstOrDefault()
```

with:

```
// At this point, orderByExp is c => c.ActionDate
var orderByDescendingCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { childType, orderByExp.Body.Type },
    propertyGetter, orderByExp
);
Expression propertySelector = propertyAccess;
// If value type property and not nullable, convert it to nullable
if (propertySelector.Type.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertySelector.Type) == null)
    propertySelector = Expression.Convert(propertySelector, typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(propertySelector.Type));
var selectCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new Type[] { childType, propertySelector.Type },
    orderByDescendingCall, Expression.Lambda(propertySelector, childInParam)
);
propertyGetter = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", new Type[] { propertySelector.Type },
    selectCall
);
```

Comment: I'm using LINQPad to work this out. With your Expression.Call, I'm getting the message 'No generic method 'OrderByDescending' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments.' Am I missing a using clause? `childType` and `orderByExp.Body.Type` are both `DateTime`. `propertyGetter.Type` is `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'1[PublicationSystem.Model.ActionItem]`

Comment: `childType` should be `ChildModel`. Your sample class is incorrect, `MyChildren` should be `IEnumerable<ChildModel>`, or `ICollection<ChildModel>` or `List<ChildModel>` in order to make your manual expression examples even compile.

Comment: I was using the wrong variable to get the type. I'm making progress now.